# VS2019 SignTool Error, but I've never set this project up to use any sort of certificate

Tags: visual-studio

Going back to a a Visual Studio C# project I hadn't touched in about 6 months in Visual Studio 2019 and trying to build/launch it again.

I had previously built and ran this project on the same PC. However, my company has since migrated to using OneDrive, if that is relevant, though I got the same error when running the solution from a folder not backed up by OneDrive.

All of a sudden getting on build:
`Failed to sign bin\Debug\app.publish\<exe name>.exe SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.`

Thing is, I never had this project setup to use a certificate (meaning Properties -> Signing -> "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" has always been unchecked.  To be honest I didnt even know this setting existed until today after looking at other questions.

I cant find the bin\Debug\app.publish\ directory in the project folder either.  My output path is bin\Debug and the .exe resides there.

Any ideas what could cause this and how to resolve it?

I've tried running Visual Studio as admin and that did not help.
I've tried running the same solution copied to a folder NOT backed up by OneDrive and that did not help.